# Error for word2vec with GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

the version of python is 3.6
I tried to execute my code but, there are still some errors as below:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "C:\Users\tmdgu\Desktop\NLP-master1\NLP-master\Ontology_Construction.py",
>   line 55, in 
>       , binary=True)
>
> File "E:\Program
>   Files\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py",
>   line 1282, in load_word2vec_format
>       raise DeprecationWarning("Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.")
>
> DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use
>   gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.

how to fix the code? or is the path to data wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a warning, not a fatal error. Your code likely still works.

"Deprecation" means a function's use has been marked by the authors as no longer encouraged.

The function typically still works, but may not for much longer – becoming unreliable or unavailable in some future library release. Often, there's a newer, more-preferred way to do the same thing, so you don't trigger the warning message.

Your warning message points you at the now-preferred way to load word-vectors of that format: use `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` instead.

Did you try using that, instead of whatever line of code (not shown in your question) that you were trying before seeing the warning?